# Horizontal line for two column

Tags: line-spacing

I have

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\end{document}
```

However, this line crosses the two columns. I just want the line cross the first column.

Answer (score 6):

Use `\linewidth` for the width of the current environment (in this case, the current column). Use `\textwidth` for the width of the whole text block on the page.